# If an regex expression is in a string , how can I exec the regex?

Tags: regex, perl

Like this :

```
$pattern = " /(\d{4})\s*-\s*(\d{2})\s*-\s*(\d{2})\s*(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})\.(\d+)/" ;
 $_ = "1972-01-01 00:00:00.0" ;
```

How can I execute the regex in the $Pattern by **using Perl** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the match operator.

```
$_ =~ /$pattern/
```

Comment: Thank you , That looks good . Do you know that how to execute a string as a Perl command ? I sereach to find a command : eval , but I test it , It can't work

Comment: i think eval must be ok for that.